# NullPointerException no Java web

Tags: java, jsp, nullpointerexception

Estou tendo um problema em um JSP que deveria inserir um projeto ao meu trabalho me retornando como erro, esta praticamente idêntico um exercício que fiz anteriormente, logo não entendo o motivo do erro.

Erro:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
[/jsp/projeto/validaInserirProjeto.jsp] at line [14]

11:     
12:     Funcionario funcionario = (Funcionario) session.getAttribute("UsuarioLogado");
13:     
14:     Projeto projeto = new Projeto(0, nome, descricao, dataObtido, dataEntregue, funcionario.getIdFuncionario());
15:     ProjetoController projCont = new ProjetoController();
16:     projeto = projCont.inserirProjeto(projeto);
17: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.jsp.projeto.validaInserirProjeto_jsp._jspService(validaInserirProjeto_jsp.java:128)
```

```xml
<%
    String nome = request.getParameter("NOME");
    String descricao = request.getParameter("DESCRICAO");
    String dataObtido = request.getParameter("DATAOBTENCAO");
    String dataEntregue = request.getParameter("DATAENTREGUE");

    Funcionario funcionario = (Funcionario) session.getAttribute("UsuarioLogado");

    Projeto projeto = new Projeto(0, nome, descricao, dataObtido, dataEntregue, funcionario.getIdFuncionario());
    ProjetoController projCont = new ProjetoController();
    projeto = projCont.inserirProjeto(projeto);
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Projeto cadastrado</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Projeto cadastrado com sucesso em seu inventario, <%=funcionario.getNome()%></h1><br><br>
        <h1>Id Projeto           =  <%=projeto.getIdProjeto()%></h1>
        <h1>Nome                   =  <%=projeto.getNome()%></h1>
        <h1>Descrição              =  <%=projeto.getDescricao()%></h1>
        <h1>Data Obtenção          =  <%=projeto.getDataObtido()%></h1>
        <h1>Data Entregue         =  <%=projeto.getDataEntregue()%></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Posta o erro completo, dessa forma não tem como saber onde está o erro.

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/jsp/projeto/validaInserirProjeto.jsp] at line [14]

11:     
12:     Funcionario funcionario = (Funcionario) session.getAttribute("UsuarioLogado");
13:     
14:     Projeto projeto = new Projeto(0, nome, descricao, dataObtido, dataEntregue, funcionario.getIdFuncionario());
15:     ProjetoController projCont = new ProjetoController();
16:     projeto = projCont.inserirProjeto(projeto);
17:

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.jsp.jsp.projeto.validaInserirProjeto_jsp._jspService(validaInserirProjeto_jsp.java:128)

Comment: Você pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar as informações do erro, dessa forma a informação fica concentrada em um único lugar

Comment: Sim, na verdade desde o inicio eu tinha colocado completo, mas editaram a minha dúvida por algum motivo retirando toda parte mais importante que era o erro em si. Atualizei novamente, obrigado pelo conselho.

Comment: No valida inserir projeto vai apenas até a linha 36. Eu não estou entendendo o que esta dando de errado.

Comment: Tem como por o mais níveis do _stacktrace_?

Comment: `funcionario` é nulo.

Answer (score 1):

```
Funcionario funcionario = (Funcionario) session.getAttribute("UsuarioLogado");
```

No caso, não existe instância do funcionário. Ao chamar `funcionario.getIdFuncionario()` gera o erro.

NullPointerException é uma exceção que indica que a aplicação tentou usar uma referência de um objeto que estava com valor nulo

Comment: Sinto muito, mas se for `NullPointerException` (como aponta o título da pergunta) não tem nada a ver com o valor zero

Comment: vi agora, deveria ter colocado nulo, mas já corrigi!

Comment: Passar nulo no construtor não causa NPE. O que causa NPE é tentar acessar um método ou atributo de uma variável cujo valor é nulo. E muitas vezes é aceitável passar nulo no construtor